# Problem programming PIC18F97J60 with PicKit2

Tags: pic, programmer

I'm having a problem programming a PIC18F97J60 with pk2cmd.exe. Using the same hex file I can program the device fine with MPLAB and the PicKit2 programming utility, but I'd like to be able to program the chip from the command line. The chip will program, but verify fails. I should mention that I have the code protect bits set on the PIC18F97J60.

Original Configuration:
 - PK2CMD.EXE v1.20
 - Device File v1.55.00
 - PICkit2 Firmware v2.32.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is a problem with the device file that comes with v1.20 of pk2cmd.exe.
Reverting to the device file that comes v1.01b of pk2cmd.exe fixes the issue.
Working configuration:
 - PK2CMD.EXE v1.20
 - Device File v1.42.00 (Comes with PK2CMD.EXE v1.01b)
 - PICkit2 Firmware v2.32.00